# Pybind11 keep-alive won't keep object alive

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am having an issue with pybind. I want a python object that is passed in to c++ be kept alive. I followed it's documentation and used what I think is the proper api(py::keep_alive<1,2>). But the object seems to be killed as soon as it's passed down to C++ unless I hold an instance of it in python.

How I set my bindings:

```cpp
pybind11::class_<EventManager>(m, "EventManager")
            .def(pybind11::init<>())
            .def("AddListener", &EventManager::AddListener)
            .def("RemoveListener", &EventManager::RemoveListener)
            .def("TriggerEvent", &EventManager::TriggerEvent, 
                pybind11::keep_alive<1, 2>())
            .def("QueueEvent", &EventManager::QueueEvent, 
                pybind11::keep_alive<1, 2>())
            .def_static("CreateListenerDelegate", 
                &Imperium::EventManager::CreateListenerDelegateFromScript, 
                pybind11::keep_alive<1, 0>(),
                pybind11::return_value_policy::take_ownership);
```

Relevant portion of the event manager class:

```cpp
                void EventManager::TriggerEvent(const EventPointer pEvent) {
                auto _foundList = mEventListenersDelegatesMap.find(pEvent.get()->GetEventType());
                if (_foundList != mEventListenersDelegatesMap.end()){
                    EventListenerDelegatesList& _listenerDelegateList = _foundList->second;
                    for (auto _delegate = _listenerDelegateList.begin(); _delegate != _listenerDelegateList.end(); ++_delegate){
                        EventListenerDelegate _listenerDelegate = (*_delegate);
                        _listenerDelegate(pEvent);
                    }
                }
            }

            void EventManager::QueueEvent(const EventPointer pEvent) {
                auto _foundList = mEventListenersDelegatesMap.find(pEvent->GetEventType());
                if (_foundList != mEventListenersDelegatesMap.end()){
                    mEventQueue.Push(pEvent);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Calling it from Python

```py
class TestSystem6(klaz.System):
    def __init__(self):
        System.__init__(self);
        self.mEventListener = None;
        self.mEvent = TestEvent();
    def Initialize(self, document):
        print("init system 6")
    def Save(self, document):
        print("save system 6")
    def GetName(self):
        return "TestSystem6"
    def Update(self, deltaTime):
        print("DeltaTime System 6: %d", deltaTime);
        if deltaTime > 3:
            self.GetEngine().GetEventManager().QueueEvent(TestEvent());
            self.SetStatus(imperium.Status.Finished)
    def Destroy(self):
        print("Destroying System 6");
```

If however, I pass in the system that i hold a reference to via self.mEvent , then it works. But passing it via initializing and sending it over such as in the update method above. Does not work and creates a null pointer when the listener is called.

Any ideas on what I migth be doing wrong?